# Need help about Paypal Express Checkout API REST with SDK PHP

Tags: php, paypal-rest-sdk, express-checkout

I've some problem to fix about API Paypal Express Checkout (REST version) that I use with the PHP SDK.

I can execute the transaction by doing $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext), the statut of the transaction is well indicated as "approved".

My trouble is that although the transaction is well present of the activity list of the sandbox acount that i use for my tests, the transaction i still labelised as "pending" while the transaction was completed almost 24 hours ago.
Is there still a step to perform after the execute ?

I would also like to know which method of which object I should use to get  transaction fees cost ?

Thank you for your help and good day to all!

Mickaël

Comment: I think you mean "retrieve transaction costs", not "recover transaction costs"? The meaning is totally different. Sorry, for not being more helpful.

Comment: OK, I've changed some words. Thanks for your suggestion KIKO

Comment: QUESTION MOVED HERE : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51891187/paypal-express-checkout-rest-api-payment-status-is-pending-instead-of-completed