# PAYPAL Express Checkout REST API, Payment status is pending instead of completed

Tags: php, rest, express, paypal, checkout

I've a problem with the Express Checkout REST API : after that the user has approuved the transaction with the paypal form, I call the "execute" method by passing the payment attributs (token, id, payerId,...). In the returned data, the status of the payment is indicated as "approved".

[image]

My trouble is that although the payment is well present of the activity list of the sandbox acount that i use for my tests, it still labelised as "pending".

I've tried to use the REST API with the PHP SDK and without the PHP SDK (I'm calling URL's with Curl), I've the same problem !
I'm using the same currency of the default user currency and the manual approbation is well disabled for the user.

I'm working on this problem since 1 month and I can't solve it !
Please, anyone has a solution or a part of response?

Thankz by advance,

Mickaël

Comment: Check if the Payment Review option is enabled or not in your PayPal account.

Comment: Thankz for your response. You speak about the seller account or the buyer account ? As I said in my post the manual approbation is well disabled for the customer.

Comment: Payment Review option in the Seller account.

Comment: Can you give me the path to disable it? I looked in the tab "My applications and references" and in the tab "My account" without finding the solution. Once again, thank you for your help.

Comment: Hope, this will be helpful - [Why do I need to manually accept or deny a PayPal payment?](https://www.paypal.com/in/smarthelp/article/why-do-i-need-to-manually-accept-or-deny-a-payment-faq1783)